# Need to query tile38 through java

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

This is the url to Tile38 db https://github.com/tidwall/tile38

Actually as per the given example in java I was able to do a get and set of entries to the collection but I want to scan the collection and execute the nearby query using JAVA. Please help me to achieve this!!!

Tile38 java example page [enter link description here](https://github.com/tidwall/tile38/wiki/Java-example-(lettuce))

Answer (score 0):

Tile38 is based on Lettuce java client for redis :

You can use this maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>biz.paluch.redis</groupId>
  <artifactId>lettuce</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0.Beta1</version>
</dependency>
```

This is an example as descriped in this link : https://github.com/tidwall/tile38/wiki/Java-example-(lettuce)